# KafkaConsumer reads from old partitions after rebalance, does not try to update state on poll()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Java, Kafka version 0.10.2.1

My KafkaConsumer is stuck in a state when it thinks it has some partitions assigned, is able to poll() for new messages but then it fails to commit because of

```
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced ...
```

So it polls again successfully (?!) and fails to commit again in a loop.

There is a second consumer in a separate thread in the same group that is in correct state, it has all the partitions assigned and can commit offsets. Logs of what's happening (consumer-1 is in broken state):

```
2017-09-28 10:16:03,384 INFO  [         consumer-1] - Flushing size: 128, delay: 14 seconds, reason: periodical
2017-09-28 10:16:03,384 INFO  [         consumer-1] - Partition assignment [topic-15, topic-14, topic-11, topic-10, topic-13, topic-12, topic-9, topic-8]
2017-09-28 10:16:03,420 ERROR [         consumer-1] - Commit failed. Should rejoin the group on next poll()
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:702)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:581)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1090)
    at cmy.package.ResourceProcessor.flushAndCommitOffset(ResourceProcessor.java:116)
    at cmy.package.ResourceProcessor.run(ResourceProcessor.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2017-09-28 10:16:13,998 INFO  [         consumer-1] - Flushing size: 6, delay: 10 seconds, reason: periodical
2017-09-28 10:16:13,999 INFO  [         consumer-1] - Partition assignment [topic-15, topic-14, topic-11, topic-10, topic-13, topic-12, topic-9, topic-8]
2017-09-28 10:16:13,999 INFO  [         consumer-0] - Flushing size: 164, delay: 19 seconds, reason: periodical
2017-09-28 10:16:13,999 INFO  [         consumer-0] - Partition assignment [topic-15, topic-14, topic-11, topic-10, topic-13, topic-12, topic-7, topic-6, topic-9, topic-8, topic-3, topic-2, topic-5, topic-4, topic-1, topic-0]
2017-09-28 10:16:14,003 ERROR [         consumer-1] - Commit failed. Should rejoin the group on next poll()
org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member. This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time message processing. You can address this either by increasing the session timeout or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.sendOffsetCommitRequest(ConsumerCoordinator.java:702)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.commitOffsetsSync(ConsumerCoordinator.java:581)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.commitSync(KafkaConsumer.java:1090)
    at cmy.package.ResourceProcessor.flushAndCommitOffset(ResourceProcessor.java:116)
    at cmy.package.ResourceProcessor.run(ResourceProcessor.java:89)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code that starts consumer:

```
   package my.package;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.SECONDS;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CommitFailedException;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.WakeupException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AutowireCapableBeanFactory;

import com.github.rholder.retry.RetryException;
import com.github.rholder.retry.Retryer;
import com.github.rholder.retry.RetryerBuilder;
import com.github.rholder.retry.StopStrategies;
import com.github.rholder.retry.WaitStrategies;
import com.google.common.base.Throwables;

public class ResourceProcessor implements Runnable {
    private static Retryer<Void> retryer = RetryerBuilder.<Void>newBuilder()
            .retryIfException()
            .withWaitStrategy(WaitStrategies.fibonacciWait(1000, 60, SECONDS))
            .withStopStrategy(StopStrategies.neverStop())
            .<Void>build();

    private final MyConfig config;
    private final int index;
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;

    private volatile KafkaConsumer<byte[], MyValue> consumer;
    private volatile SinkTask sink;

    private int processedSize = 0;
    private Instant lastFlushTime = Instant.now();
    private Properties consumerConfig;
    private String name;
    private Logger logger;

    public ResourceProcessor(
            Properties consumerConfig,
            MyConfig config,
            int index,
            ResourcePrimaryStore resourceStore,
            AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory) {
        this.consumerConfig = consumerConfig;
        this.config = config;
        this.index = index;
        this.resourceStore = resourceStore;
        this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
    }

    public void run() {
        name = String.format("consumer-%d", index);
        logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(name);
        Thread.currentThread().setName(name);
        logger.info("Starting");

        sink = createSink();
        consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(consumerConfig);

        try {
            consumer.subscribe(config.topics(),
                    new PartitionsRevokeCallback(() -> flushAndCommitOffset("partitions revoke")));
            while (true) {
                ConsumerRecords<byte[], MyValue> records = consumer.poll(10000);
                records.forEach(v -> {
                    sink.put(v.value());
                    processedSize = processedSize + 1;
                });
                if (shouldFlush()) {
                    flushAndCommitOffset("periodical");
                }
            }
        } catch (WakeupException e) {
            // Requested to shut down and do it gracefully
            flushAndCommitOffset("shutting down");
        } finally {
            consumer.close();
            sink.close();
        }
    }

    private boolean shouldFlush() {
        Duration waitUntilFlush = Duration.between(Instant.now(), lastFlushTime.plus(config.flushInterval()));
        return processedSize >= config.batchSize()
                || waitUntilFlush.isNegative() || waitUntilFlush.isZero();

    }

    private void flushAndCommitOffset(String reason) {
        logger.info("Flushing size: {}, delay: {} seconds, reason: {}",
                processedSize,
                Duration.between(lastFlushTime, Instant.now()).getSeconds(),
                reason);
        try {
            flushRetryingInfinitely();
            processedSize = 0;
            lastFlushTime = Instant.now();
            consumer.commitSync();
        } catch (CommitFailedException e) {
            logger.error("Commit failed. Should rejoin the group on next poll()", e);
        }
    }

    private void flushRetryingInfinitely() {
        try {
            retryer.call(() -> {
                logger.info("Partition assignment {}", consumer.assignment());
                sink.flush();
                return null;
            });
        } catch (ExecutionException | RetryException e) {
            // should never happen as we retry all exceptions
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
    }

    private SinkTask createSink(String sinkClass) {
        try {
            return (SinkTask) beanFactory.createBean(Class.forName("my.package.SinkTask"));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw Throwables.propagate(e);
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        consumer.wakeup();
    }

}
```

This broken state appeared after after I stopped-started my database and so `flushRetryingInfinitely()` was retrying for some time preventing KafkaConsumer from calling poll().